# Firebase.configure() in xCode cause Thread 1: signal SIGABRT : terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException on App Delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, appdelegate, sigabrt

Firebase.configure causes crash on App delegate file once I run, showing the following next to app delegate class

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

In console, it shows :

> 37  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Any help please?

Note: I have Google `.plist` file on the project , and the right one ( I tried several times in like 8 or 10 project till now, no success)

Pod installed :

```
Installing Firebase (4.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.4)
Installing FirebaseCore (4.0.8)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.4)
..
```

Code :

```
import UIKit 
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

Please help me out, I really need it and it's been 2 days and like 12 hours infront of xCode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue seems to be happening when 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file is missing within your project path. Delete the existing 'GoogleService-Info.plist'. Download again from the Firebase service, and add the '.plist' File, make sure you select the correct project target. Once added, clean and build again.

Answer (score 1):

Set the target membership for the plist file

select GoogleSErvice-Info.plist in the Xcode project navigator
then enable the target membership for the file in the utilities pane for File Inspector

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although the GoogleService-Info(1).plist file was already present in my Xcode project.

In my case, I had already an GoogleService-Info.plist file in my Downloads directory, from a previous project. Because of that, the next file had been automatically named "GoogleService-Info(1).plist" ...and this is how I've imported in Xcode.

Because of this minor renaming of the file, I've spend more than 1 hour not knowing why on earth my app crashes!

Make sure your Google.plist file has the right name, which is: GoogleService-Info.plist

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have `"GoogleService-Info.plist"` is present within your project

```
replace FirebaseApp.configure() with Firebase.FirebaseApp.configure()
```